# Recommended Projected Coordinate Reference System for Land Use Analysis in Northern Spain and Western Australia

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, utm, land-cover

I am working on a land use analysis project within QGIS that involves studying regions in Northern Spain and Western Australia. These regions span across multiple UTM zones, and I'm unsure about the best coordinate reference system (CRS) to use for each of the regions. Therefore, I am looking for a suitable CRS for each of the regions and not one CRS that covers both.

The analysis is based on the land cover classes by [Esri | Sentinel-2 Land Cover](https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/landcoverexplorer/#mapCenter=10.787%2C51.665%2C11&mode=step&timeExtent=2017%2C2022&year=2022&downloadMode=true).
In the following picture you can see the first processing steps for northern Spain, where I want to reproject the ESRI land cover raster files, build a virtual raster, clip them to the North Spain region and then get the relevant land cover classes by Reclassification including some buffers around them.
[image: Screenshot model builder]

Since the regions cover more than one UTM zone, I'm concerned about potential distortions and problems that might arise from selecting a single UTM zone. I want to ensure that the chosen CRS minimizes distortions while allowing for an accurate spatial analysis. Northern Spain covers the UTM zones 29T, 30T, 31T, 30S and Western Australia even more.
[image]

Can anyone suggest suitable coordinate reference systems or projections that would be appropriate for conducting a land use analysis in either Northern Spain or Western Australia?
Is the Australian Albers EPSG:3577 a suitable CRS?

Comment: According to https://epsg.io/25830, EPSG:25380 (ETRS89 / UTM zone 30N) cover whole spain

Comment: "Northern Spain and Western Australia"? Aren't they on opposite sides of the globe?

Comment: It's not 100% clear from your question whether you are asking for a single CRS for both Northern Spain and Western Australia, or one CRS for Northern Spain and a different CRS for Western Australia. Can you clarify in your question?

Comment: For WA, EPSG:3577 (GDA94 / Australian Albers) would be suitable, but you should consider using the newer [EPSG:9473](https://epsg.io/9473) (GDA2020 / Australian Albers).

Comment: I need a seperate CRS for each of the two regions.
Sorry, that this was unclear, I edited the question.
I will try EPSG:3577 and EPSG:9473 for Western Australia.
For Spain EPSG:25380 did not work for me as the generated output only contained the UTM zone 30N. I tried ESPG:2062, which worked. But I am not sure if this is the correct choice.

Comment: For Northern Spain, I suggest you to use EPSG:25830 (there's a typo in @J.R's comment above)